WiFi option is not visible
My laptop (Ubuntu v 22.04.02) was connected to WiFi and was working fine,but just a couple of hours ago the WiFi option is not available (hidden). I have spent some time  searching on internet  to fix it but none the suggested methods work (to my understanding).if you are using Ubuntu,just to ask u If you  have ever faced this kind of problem.

What have you tried to do when you could not see the Wifi option (on the taskbar?)? Did you restart your machine? Do you have other devices connected to the Wifi network? What Wifi adapter do you have? Which "suggested methods" did you try? If you don't tell us we'll likely point out the same answers, right?

Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and provide the results from the wireless script
